# Less Than XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to pull products on sale from an xml file. Here is my XML:

```
<product>
    <programname>​QVC.​com​</programname>
    <programurl>​http​://​www.​qvc.​com​</programurl>
    <catalogname>​QVC Product Catalog​</catalogname>
    <lastupdated>​04/​17/​2013​</lastupdated>
    <name>Product 1</name>
    <keywords>​CTA Digital, Electronics, Video Games, Hardware. Nintendo Wii​</keywords>
    <manufacturer>​CTA Digital​</manufacturer>
    <currency>​USD​</currency>
    <saleprice>​15.​96​</saleprice>
    <price>​17.​96​</price>
    <retailprice>​17.​96​</retailprice>
</product>
```

I used the following xpath but it didn't work: /product[saleprice < retailprice]. I'm looking for the output to be true for any product where saleprice is less than retail price. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: That's not an XML document, because it has more than one root-level element.

Comment: `//product[saleprice < retailprice]` or `/root/product[saleprice < retailprice]` works well when I repair the document to be XML valid.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
/product[number(saleprice) < number(retailprice)]
```

Comment: You'll need to make that start `//` since that has to be another element around the products for the XML to be valid, but other than that, this appears to work. This is my test script: http://pastebin.com/CG8cgvLM

Comment: @Quentin: you're perfectly right. however, the question has been edited by now. thx anyway

Comment: I edited it to give a better picture of what I'm dealing with b/c there is only one root. Thanks for your help. Solved.